Xpub used to create vendor addresses, btc not seen in wallet. How choose which derivation path is needed?
2020 I used xpub to generate btc addresses. Little did I know these would not be picked up by my wallet.
I still have all the keys for my wallet, but any wallet program does not seem to be able to see the btc I have.
There are four transactions to different addresses which are owned by my wallet.
How do work out the correct derivation path to use?
I hope this makes sense to someone


I used xpub to generate btc addresses.

"xpub" means several different things. Lets assume you refer to the "xpub-cli" application named xpub published by swan-bitcoin four years ago

How do work out the correct derivation path to use?

Only you know what derivation path you specified back in 2020. The derivation path used by swan's xpub depends on what command-line arguments you provided.
They give several examples such as
$ xpub derive \
ypub6XFA3jGfowZ6umedCYjPiMUeFetNQYDpUpHKqbrE3bzwawLmLbvYCYaUpiwZ6FHwU951b9dLd6hSvFJwHv763vvpXUV44PW62rtesm5g4wa \
 -n3 -c5 --purpose p2sh

[
  {
    path: "m/49'/0'/5'/0/0",
    address: '3PEpUeFZUWJPrbdKGzaNeEpekSPpSbVSzL'
  },
  {
    path: "m/49'/0'/5'/0/1",
    address: '3AedcVmzeoUF4tHkzDHM6wp7WLoo668KwT'
  },
  {
    path: "m/49'/0'/5'/0/2",
    address: '3BpPnS79WUzRQMG2DCNUKHgSKCaNoAMPCu'
  }
]

Note that the 5 in the path comes from the BIP-44 account number specified in -c5
Only you know what exact command line you used in 2020.

At the time I inputed the xpub (which I’m sure I extracted from Exodus) this then gave me multiple btc addresses. When I load this wallet up I do not get the same xpub and the only way for me to find the addresses which btc was sent to is with the xpub I still have noted down. Hope this adds some more information
